# Does "GMT Standard Time" imply BST?

Tags: c#, timezone

I am confused by "GMT Standard Time".

I have data which is stored as DATE only, but is actually 6PM BST.

I read it in and add 18 hours. I then try to convert to UTC. My initial understanding is that the conversion would NOT take into account Daylight time (as "GMT Standard Time" and UTC are both WITHOUT daylight time). I thought I would have to test for daylight time on the source and then make an adjustment.

However, ConvertTime appears to know about Daylight time in the source and makes the appropriate change.

That seems odd to me - is this the expected behaviour?

```
    TimeZoneInfo gmtZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
    TimeZoneInfo utcZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");
    public static CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;


            string SomeDT = "27/01/2000"; //First BST day
            var sourceDT = DateTime.ParseExact(SomeDT, "dd/MM/yyyy", ci).AddHours(18); 
            var utcDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(sourceDT, gmtZone, utcZone);

            // At this point utcDT has already been changed so test below is redundant. 
            // That Suggest "GMT Standard Time" is actually "Daylight Time" i.e.BST

            if (gmtZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(sourceDT))
            {
                utcDT = utcDT.AddHours(-1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not BST");
            }
```

Comment: The Brits pop their beers by GMT in the winter, BST in the summer.  Windows does not keep separate names for timezones that only differ in daylight observance.  So "GMT Standard Time" really does equal BST when you pick a sunny day.  Also the reason that "UTC" has its own name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the time zone IDs in Windows are confusing. Even though the ID is "GMT Standard Time", the time zone referred to by that ID is *really* "UK time"... like "Europe/London" in IANA. So yes, it will observe DST.

If you want genuine UTC, just use `TimeZoneInfo.Utc`.

(Alternatively, use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) or something similar instead, and the more standard [IANA time zones](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)...)

Comment: Is the same true for Eastern Standard Time? WIll that actually represent Daylight time (EDT) during the summer?

Comment: @ManInMoon: Yup. From the docs for `TimeZoneInfo.Id`: "The value of the Id property is usually, but not always, identical to that of the StandardName property." (It actually means "... in an English locale" because StandardName is localized, but that's a different kettle of fish.)

Comment: So if all my data is in "Local" UK time and I convert as above - I will get proper UTC WITHOUT doing a IsDaylightSavingTime test myself?

Comment: @ManInMoon: Yes. Although it would be better to start off with a UTC value in the first place. And again, I'd personally recommend using Noda Time anyway, of course - it aims to make this sort of thing far simpler :)

Comment: Is the odd terminology of "Standard" explained on MSDN anywhere?

Comment: @ManInMoon: I think it's more an odd choice of using the standard name as the ID than anything else.

Comment: @ManInMoon - This, and more examples of confusing ids, are in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) in the section the the Microsoft Time Zone Database.